# Math Challenge: Create 8

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Using only $2$, $7$, and $7$ (each one must be used only once) and only using the operations $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $\textrm{^}$, and parentheses, make 8. You can also use decimals.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possible answer is:

> (7 / .7) - 2

Comment: Maybe someone can confirm with a proof/full explanation of some sort(or prove me wrong!) but I'm fairly confident this is the only solution (besides adding negatives to both numerator and denominator).

Comment: @TCooper proven you [wrong](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101870/33365)

Comment: @deusovi, why are you used brackets?

Comment: @Nick Just for visual clarity. They weren't necessary, but I thought it might make it slightly faster to parse.

Comment: Well: Any a / (a * n) where n != 0 results in 'n'. 7 / 0.7 = 7 / (0.7 * 10) = 10. 10 - 2 = 8. Although the zero-less decimal notation is quite controversial over here in Europe!

Answer (score 7):

Under a suitable interpretation of "you can also use decimals", another answer is

> $7 + .\overline7 + .\overline2$, where the bars represent repeating decimals, so that the expression is $7 + 0.7777{\ldots} + 0.2222{\ldots}$.

Comment: Had this in mind, too, but that's a broad interpretation of "decimals".

Comment: I would say the problem isn't the deimcals, it uses the digits more than once and/or uses a disallowed operator

Comment: It's not so clear to me. Why is the decimal point an allowed operator? It's because of our interpretation of the imprecise "You can also use decimals". A repeating bar is a standard notation for repeating decimals, so that seems within a reasonable interpretation to me.

Answer (score 7):

Without allowing any tricks, especially not:

> Zeroless decimals, like `.7` instead of `0.7`

Then here are all the solutions:

> There are
>  no
>  solutions.

Justification:

```
import itertools
import operator
d1 = lambda x,y: 10*x + y
d2 = lambda x,y: x + y/10
d3 = lambda x,y: x + y/100
for f,g in itertools.permutations([operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.truediv, operator.floordiv, operator.pow, d1,d2,d3, operator.xor]*2, 2):
  for x,y,z in itertools.permutations([2,7,7]):
    try:
      if (g(f(x,y), z) == 8):
        print('({} {} {}) {} {}'.format(x,f,y,g,z))
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError):
      pass
    try:
      if (g(x, f(y,z)) == 8):
        print('{} {} ({} {} {})'.format(x,g,y,f,z))
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError):
      pass
```

Comment: This might be the most pedantic answer I've ever seen... but you aren't wrong lol

Answer (score 4):

Interpreting the constraints as purely typographic:

> $7^{(2)}/7$
>  
>  ($x^{(n)}$ is commonly used to denote the rising factorial $x(x+1)...(x+n-1)$)

or (also rather mathsy):

> $7+\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)$
>  
>  ($\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol which for a prime $p$ and a natural number $n$ is defined as $0$ if $p$ divides $n$, as $1$ if $n$ is a "quadratic residue mod $p$", i.e. $n=a^2 \mod p$ for some non multiple $a$ of $p$, and as $-1$ if $n$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod $p$, i.e. no such $a$ exists; in our case $p=7,n=2$ we could choose $a$ to be either $3$ or $4$)
>  
>  Unwieldy and arbitrary as this may look the concepts around the Legendre symbol are actually a pillar of elementary and not so elementary number theory.

or, bending the rules a tiny bit (there are many kinds of parentheses):

> $\langle \{7,7+2\} \rangle$ or $\langle (7,7+2) \rangle$ or $\langle [7,7+2] \rangle$
>  
>  (physicists use angular parentheses for averages)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Deusovi's answer, here is another answer.

> If we allow the `^` operator to be used refer to the XOR operator $\oplus$, we can write:
>
>  $(7 \div .7)\ ^\wedge\ 2$
>
>  This can be interpreted as such.
>
>  $(7 \div .7) \oplus 2$

Comment: isn't that 100, not 8?

Comment: @HugoRune I use ^ as XOR operator, not exponent

Comment: @HugoRune I suppose it's fair to call C/C++ (or Python for that matter) a rather common language.

Comment: Also, but perhaps that's just me, programming is about the only domain where leaving out the leading zero in a decimal fraction is borderline acceptable.

Comment: Though ⊕ is much more common as a XOR operator, ^ is readily available in ASCII. I have never seen ⩒, ⩛, ↮, and ≢ used in the literature. Also, when in Programmer mode, the Windows built-in calculator uses ^ as XOR in the keyboard.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I'd say that many, if not most, programming languages use ^ as the XOR operator and & as the AND operator.

Comment: @teed I edited your answer to add Math/LaTex formatting. Hopefully this will clear things up for future readers.

Comment: initial zeros are commonly omitted in ballistics too, and the point is often silent, eg  .22 .357 .45

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is mathematically valid but at least it works on my calculator:

> $7^{(.)/2}+7$ where the lone decimal is interpreted as a zero

Comment: You have to use 2 as well

Comment: @LukasRotter not sure that's %100 clear from OP wording ("only once" is not "exactly once"). Besides, once you accept what the calculator accepts it is trivial to make the 2 go away.

Comment: @LukasRotter As Paul Panzer said, its trivial to use the 2. In fact I edited it to use the 2 as well just in case that's what the OP meant

Answer (score 0):

Does $\lceil7+2/7\rceil$ count where $\lceil . \rceil$ denotes the ceiling function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions?

If that doesn't count what about $7+7^{[.2]}$ where $[.]$ is the rounding function to the next integer?

Comment: Welcome to PSE! - Unfortunately, the question reads "and **only** using the operations +, -, *, /, ^, and parentheses, make 8." The ceiling function $\lceil x\rceil$ is not listed.

Comment: Well, in a broad sense $\lceil$ and $\rceil$ *look* like parenthesis, don't they? ;)

Comment: I mean... they *are* listed under the "Brackets" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Brackets... didn't know that! :)